# MySQL gap lock behavior isn't in line with expectation

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

**Problem description:**

In mysql 8.0, I started a transaction and executed `SELECT * FROM child WHERE id > 1000 FOR UPDATE;` (transaction one), then I started another transaction and executed `update child set id = id+10 where id = 101;` (transaction two),and **there is a row of `id = 101` in table `child`**, but this transaction two was blocked.

If I execute `update child set id = id+10 where id = 102;`(transaction three)  and no row of `id = 102` exists in the table, transaction three won't be blocked and can be executed successfully.

As far as I concerned, mysql 8.0 gap lock will only locks rows whose ids are greater than 1000, but in the second transaction, the row id is 101 and not greater than 1000, so the two transactions would not conflict with each other. So why was transaction two blocked by transaction one?

**Additional details as below :**

1. Table `child` structure:

`` CREATE TABLE `child` (\n  `id` int NOT NULL,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ``

2. All data in table `child`:

```
mysql root@localhost:test> select * from child;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 90   |
| 101  |
| 105  |
| 106  |
| 109  |
| 111  |
| 1007 |
+------+
7 rows in set
```

3. All mysql 8.0 configurations are as default.
4. The two transactions are in parallel.

Comment: *then I started another transaction* This transaction is parallel or nested?

Comment: The locking behaviour will depend on your data, so please add details about it. Specifically: do you have an id that lies in the gap (e.g. a value from 112 to 1001) in your table? If not, that behaviour is expected. (If you still want to know why, we can elaborate, but would need a confirmation about your data).

Comment: I added necessary details above, really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Having the row 111 in your table would give you a primary key violation when you do your update of 101 to 111, nevertheless, your sample data confirmed my general assumptions about the gap lock covering the area where the update would place the row.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying a bit, a [lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html) will always be attached to existing objects, e.g. a row.

Assume you have the ids 90, 101, 105, 106, 109, 110 and 1007 in your table. Note that I changed your sample row 111 to 110, as otherwise, the update from 101 to 111 would fail due to a primary key violation, before getting into trouble with locks.

If MySQL needs to issue a lock for `WHERE id > 1000`, it will not (as it cannot) keep track of the exact value `> 1000`. It will instead take the existing object that is closest to that value, which in your case is the row with id 110, and adds a gap lock that covers the space from 110 to 1006. And another lock + gap lock on the row with id 1007, that covers the space from 1007 and above.

Yes, this covers more space than needed. But that lock includes the space that *is* needed, which is the important aspect.

Your `update child set id = id+10 where id = 101` now would move the row into the locked space, and thus has to wait for the existing lock to be released. So this is actually the expected behaviour due to how MySQL works.

If you would have another row between 112 and 1000, the gap lock could instead start there, and your update transaction wouldn't have to wait.

Practically, this is an issue especially with small tables (or with specific update/insert-patterns). If you add more and more rows, the probability that a random update hits the one "over-covered" gap will get lower.